# R: How to merge two files loaded with spark_read_csv

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm working on data loaded with `spark_read_csv` in this way:

```
library(sparklyr)
connection <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
all_data <- spark_read_csv(sc, "D:/my_data.csv")
```

after working on this data I realize that I need to combine it with another file. The second file has the same variables and characteristics as the first one and I would like to load it with the same method `spark_read_csv`.

So my question is the following, is it possible to load two files with the `spark_read_csv` method and then merge them? The purpose is to add the values ​​to the already existing columns of one file to the other

Answer (score 0):

You can just union the two dataframe

```
x: SparkDataFrame
y: SparkDataFrame

union(x, y)
```

[Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/R/union.html)